# Yammer OAuth is not going back to iOS app after redirect URL

Tags: ios, iphone, yammer

I have followed the Yammer iOS SDK [provided here](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/ios-sdk), and have issues when doing the login. I have registered the app with an Expected redirect https://webpage.com.

In the YMConstans.m file, I have changed the YAMMER_AUTH_REDIRECT_URI to the same address, so everything should be working fine. However, when I run the app, it allows me to login but never redirects to the app. This means, the following method is never being called, so I cannot handle the token provided.

`- (BOOL)application: openURL: sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:`

Any ideas of what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you register the callback URI in your project's info section?

Comment: Yes, already done that @Dare. I put https://webpage.com as URL identifier and for the Item of URL Schemes the name of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the configuration of the URI was done wrong. This is the correct configuration in the Info section: 
[image]

And this is the code defined for the redirect_uri:

```
SString * const YAMMER_AUTH_REDIRECT_URI = @"whatever://example.com";
```

Finally, the expected redirect set for the application registered in Yammer should be the same:

> whatever://example.com